# Add shape to a class and access its new properties defined in the class

Tags: excel, vba, object

I wanted to create a shape, which has its own custom properties such as "IP Address", "Port Number" etc. And when I right-click on it I would like to fill in those fields/properties specific to that shape. So, I decided that I need a class which has those properties (i.e. "IP Address" etc) and I also included a shape as a variable of my class. The idea is that every shape is an object and will have the desirable properties ("IP Address" etc).

The problem is I do not know how to connect my class properties to my shape and after adding my shape in excel environment, proceed further and access/change those custom properties.
Here is the code for my class called Port:

```
    Public Switch As String
    Public Port As String
    Public IP As String
    Public Shp As Shape


    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MsgBox "Class is being initialized"
    Switch = ""
    Port = ""
    IP = ""
    Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 50, 50)
'Shp.OnAction = "Shape_Menu"
End Sub


    Sub Shape_Menu()
    MsgBox "Got Here"
    End Sub
```

For a little while, I was trying to run other methods in my class such as "Shape_Menu()" using the .OnAction Method of the shapes, but with no luck.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You could use the AlternativeText property and add your custom properties with a delimiter. This way you'll save them with your shapes and not only in memory.

Comment: Note that setting `Shp` in `Class_Initialize` through `ActiveSheet`, means `New`ing up an instance of this class will add a rectangle shape to whatever worksheet is active at that time - you will definitely want to remove any side-effects from that `Initialize` handler. Also I'd strongly recommend avoiding underscores in method names, especially if you're getting into classes and events.

Comment: *I was trying to run other methods in my class such as "Shape_Menu()" using the .OnAction Method of the shapes, but with no luck.* ...shapes' `OnAction` need a *macro* (a public procedure in a standard or worksheet module). Excel can't access any particular *instance* of your class through a shape's `OnAction`.